# how to make md-sidenav push content to the right instead of overlapping it?

Tags: html, css, angular-material

Is there any way I can make the side nav sticky so that when the side nav opens, it pushes the content of the page to the right instead of just overlapping it like https://inbox.google.com/ ?

Here is the [**plunker link**](https://plnkr.co/edit/X1CSbSyIu1JoPl5S9r7L?p=preview) of my sample work

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Angular Material style sheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="BlankApp" layout="column" ng-cloak ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<md-toolbar class="md-whiteframe-7dp" layout="row">
    <md-button class="menu" ng-click="toggleSidenav();"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></md-button>
    <h3>Hello Toolbar</h3>
</md-toolbar>

<md-content id="body-part" flex layout="row" layout-fill>
    <md-sidenav md-disable-backdrop class="md-whiteframe-7dp" md-component-id="left-side-nav"
                flex style="background: cyan">
        <span>Hello Nav..!!</span>
    </md-sidenav>
    <div flex style="padding: 10px;overflow-y: scroll; background: darkcyan">
        <span>Hello Content...!</span><br>
    </div>
</md-content>


<!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular Material Library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<!-- Your application bootstrap  -->
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you can find a way to explicitly declare `width` values for the content `div` and have that adjust accordingly on change, you should be able to get your smooth transitioning effect with your run-of-the-mill `transition` rule. You'll need javascript to detect the change in widths and update the inline style accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a relative position to the sidenav css styling:

From your Plunker:

```
md-sidenav, md-sidenav.md-locked-open, md-sidenav.md-closed.md-locked-open-add-active {
    min-width: 200px !important;
    width: 50vw !important;
    max-width: 200px !important;
    position:relative;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/cheYKMT2Mjy7Bvqv62hI?p=preview

Comment: Is there a materialistic way of doing it? The solution that you have given works but the div simply snaps to the new position instead transitioning.

Answer (score 4):

Add `mode="push"` in your `<md-sidenav>`.

```
<md-sidenav mode="push">

</md-sidenav>
```

Refer this : [Sidenave | Angular Material | Mode](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview#sidenav-mode)

Comment: He ask for a solution for MaterialJS and not for Material2 ;)

Comment: how did this get so many upvotes?

Comment: @Budi The question literally uses angular_material libraries. How is that MaterialJS ?

Comment: @rtaft I would like to understand what is the issue here? Did I misunderstand the question? Does the solution which I provided does not work what the question was asked for which was "how to make md-sidenav push content to the right instead of overlapping it" and ss per Angular docs using mode works what the question is intended for

Comment: @RaviSankarRao `1.X.X` is MaterialJS.  The example is `1.1.0-rc2`.  Budi is right.  Your solution does not work as it mixes AngularJS with Material2, you can't do that.  The link you provided uses `mat-sidenav` and not `md-sidenav`, that is the easy way to tell which is which.

Answer (score 2):

Change position absolute to static.

```
.md-sidenav {position: static;}
```

Comment: The answer works as expected. But then the div next to the sidenav is not transitioning. I want the page to be materialistic

Answer (score 1):

Faught with this issue once. The Angular Material website example uses `$mdSidenav('left').toggle();`

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']);
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $mdSidenav) {
  $scope.openLeftMenu = function() {
    $mdSidenav('left').toggle();
  };
});
```

To pull off what you are asking, use `md-is-locked-open`

This should do the trick.

md-sidenav md-is-locked-open="isSideNavOpen">...

```js
$scope.openLeftMenu = function() {
  $scope.isSideNavOpen = !$scope.isSideNavOpen;
};
```